# Need spring maven errors explanation, after applying maven-enforcer-plugin

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, maven-3, dependency-management

I am new to maven. I created a maven project and apply maven-enforcer plugin. Now when i run mvn install i get the following errors.

```
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3/commons-lang-2.3.jar (240 KB at 41.9 KB/sec)
[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.2.RELEASE  paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jpa:2.0.8
    +-org.springframework:spring-context:2.0.8
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jpa:2.0.8
    +-org.springframework:spring-dao:2.0.8
      +-org.springframework:spring-context:2.0.8
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.3.3-rc1
    +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.6.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.3.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.3.RELEASE
      +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.3.RELEASE

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jpa:2.0.8
    +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jpa:2.0.8
    +-org.springframework:spring-dao:2.0.8
      +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.3.3-rc1
    +-org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:1.3.3-rc1
      +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.3.3-rc1
    +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3-beta1
    +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.2.RELEASE paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.4.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.3.RELEASE
      +-org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.3.RELEASE

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.1 paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.2.RELEASE
    +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.1
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.2.RELEASE
    +-org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.1
      +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.1
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.5.1.RELEASE
    +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.1
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5
    +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final
    +-org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.0.Beta2
      +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.8
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final
    +-org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final
      +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.8
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final
    +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.8

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.2.RELEASE paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.3.RELEASE

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.2.RELEASE paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.4.RELEASE

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.0.Beta2
    +-org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.0.Beta2
    +-org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.1.Final
      +-org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.CR2
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.1.Final
    +-org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jpa:2.0.8
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:2.0.8
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jpa:2.0.8
    +-org.springframework:spring-dao:2.0.8
      +-org.springframework:spring-beans:2.0.8
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-oxm:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.3.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.5.1.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.3.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.3.RELEASE
      +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.3.RELEASE

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.2.RELEASE paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   +-org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-orm:3.1.4.RELEASE

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.2.RELEASE
      +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-tx:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jpa:2.0.8
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:2.0.8
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jpa:2.0.8
    +-org.springframework:spring-dao:2.0.8
      +-org.springframework:spring-core:2.0.8
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-oxm:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.5.1.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.3.RELEASE
      +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE

[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.2.RELEASE paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.2.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.2.2.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-jpa:2.0.8
    +-org.springframework:spring-jdbc:2.0.8

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.2.RELEASE paths to dependency are:
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

.....
.....

]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.641s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 05 01:18:41 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer- plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce) on project ch17_i18nSupport: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN    /MojoExecutionException
```

Here is my POM

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pk.training.basitMahmood</groupId>
<artifactId>ch17_i18nSupport</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>ch17_i18nSupport Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.171</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor-xml</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>ch17_Internatio</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>   
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules> 
                                <DependencyConvergence />
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Why i am getting these errors? what does that errors mean ? How can i solve these errors ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used 'maven-enforcer-plugin' plugin. It seems that that plugin will raise an error for different version of libs in dependency.

In you pom dependency, there are jar like org.springframework:spring-core has different version dependent by different jar. 3.1.4 and 3.2.3.

If you didn't add that plugin, there should not any error.

In the normal, we will exclude the un-necessary (or conflict) lib from dependency.

for example:

`+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.5.1.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE
and
+-pk.training.basitMahmood:ch17_i18nSupport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.3.RELEASE
    +-org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE`

both data commons and webmvc has dependency on spring-core, but data-commons is using old one. So we need to exclude spring-core from data-common like this:

`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>`